# Кривые линии на HTML/CSS/SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image]
Как это можно реализовать ? Пробовал вставить svg-код линии в html, но получается, что линия занимает площадь прямоугольника.

Comment: картинка это хорошо, но с Вашей неудачной попыткой (с кодом) будет лучше, чтобы как минимум было понятно что пробовали, в словах `линия занимает площадь прямоугольника` много разных смыслов — лучше один раз увидеть, и не стесняйтесь добавить описание задачи в вопрос — что именно вызывает сложность, какого результата добиваетесь (в том числе ограничения по коду если есть)

Comment: Ставлю svg-код первой линии(который синий)  в html, всё хорошо отображается, можно при наведении цвет менять и т.д.  Но на странице получается, что я поставил обычный блок. Это линия занимает полную площадь по x и y.

Answer (score 1):

Может сработать тег `<path>` в SVG. Просто укажите координаты для кривой линии с помощью атрибута `d`. Чтобы создать квадратную кривую линию:

```
<svg>
  <path d="M10 10 Q 25 25, 40 10" stroke="black" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

`M` - начальная точка линии, `Q` обозначает кривую Безье, где 25 25 это контрольная точка, а 40 10 - конеч. точка линии. А свойство `stroke-width` устанавливает ширину линии.

Если вы вставляете SVG-код линии в HTML, убедитесь, что ширина и высота SVG элемента соответствуют ширине и высоте линии, иначе линия будет занимать площадь прямоугольника. Если вы будете вставлять SVG-код линии в HTML проверьте, ширина и высота SVG элемента соот-т ширине и высоте линии, т.к. линия будет занимать площ. прямоугольника.

Можно еще сделать так:

```
<svg>
  <path d="M10 10 C 15 5, 25 15, 40 10" stroke="black" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

или так

```
<svg width="50" height="50">
  <path d="M10 10 Q 25 25, 40 10" stroke="black" fill="none" />
</svg>
```